# Hard limit of sine function

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

How can I compute this limit : $$\lim_{n \to \infty } {1 \over n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\left\lvert \sin k\right\rvert} $$
Thank you.

Comment: What are your thoughts and approach?

Comment: Think of which techniques you have learned in your course. Does any of those ring a bell?

Comment: I tried to apply Stolz theorem but i have not got any result.

Comment: Equidistributed sequence, ergodic process, Monte-Carlo integration - did you see any of those terms in your course? Is it analysis or statistic course?

Comment: No..it is just an analysis exercise.

Comment: You need to invoke the equidistribution theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) because the sequence $\{\left|\sin(k)\right|\}_{k\geq 0}$ is not regular enough to apply standard manipulations.

Answer (score 4):

By Weyl's [equidistribution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) the sequence $\{e^{in}\}_{n\geq 0}$ is dense in the unit circle and much more: it is equidistributed. In particular, since $\sin(k)=\text{Im}\,e^{ik}$, the limit $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|\sin(k)\right|$ is the average value of the function $\left|\sin(x)\right|$, i.e.
$$ \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(x)\,dx = \color{red}{\frac{2}{\pi}}.$$

Comment: Thanks Jack D'Aurizio. Can we solve it without this theorem?

Comment: @Gustav: I believe we cannot. As a matter of fact, we may build sequences that are dense in $[-1,1]$ such that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k$ does not exist or differs from the expected value given by the associated integral.

Comment: However, we may prove the above result by exploiting the convergents of the continued fraction of $pi$, Lagrange's theorem and the Lipschitz-continuity of the sine function: $\left|\sin(k)\right|$ is an almost-periodic sequence with respect to the periods $7,106,113,33102,\ldots$. But that is not really different than going through the equidistribution theorem.

Comment: +1. A 'naive' application of Stolz-Ces$\mathrm{\grave{a}}$ro fails !!!. It "is not regular enough to apply standard manipulations" as you pointed out in the above comments.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $|\sin k|=\sin (k \bmod \pi)$  The values of $k \bmod \pi$ will bounce around in the interval $[0,\pi)$ so you are asked for the average value of $\sin x$ over this interval.  What integral can you do to get this?

Comment: Really Ross Millikan, i didn't understand your question, can you aske it in more simple way? Thanks.

Comment: Important to note this is guaranteed because integers are not fractions of any irrational (which $\pi$ is), if the k were a fraction of $\pi$ the answer might be different.

Comment: How would you find the average value of $\sin x$ over $[0,\pi)$?

Comment: @Gustav, your expression can be interpreted as the limit of a Riemann sum.

Comment: There is a chance that limits are done before integrals are introduced and then it could be confusing.

Comment: Ross Millikan. Sorry i don't have the answer.

Comment: Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla.. How it could be interpreted as a limit of Riemann integral ?

Comment: The area under the sine curve is the same as the average value of the sine times the length of the interval.

Comment: *Bouncing around* or density is not enough: we need equidistribution, that is stronger than density.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio But if we had a non-equidistribution and density and could compute the density we could do a weighted integral instead?

Comment: @mathreadler: what does it mean *compute the density*? If it stands for *know the distribution*, well, of course, a weighted integral solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** as Jack points out below in comments I forgot the absolute value. I am sure this answer can be fixed by various means, but it would take some time, won't be pretty and probably add to any confusion already present. I should probably remove it and make a question of how to solve it using a similar technique.

---

Here is another approach, **although probably not easier than the integral**: use the addition formula

$$\sin(v+w) = \sin(v)\cos(w)+\cos(v)\sin(w)$$

**a lot**.

$$\sin(n+1) = \sin(n)\cos(1)+\cos(n)\sin(1)$$
$$\cos(n+1) = \cos(n)\cos(1)+\sin(n)\sin(1)$$

If you have learned to calculate recurrence relations with matrices for example a course in linear algebra, now is the time to put that to use.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see the relation here.

Comment: Maybe you can come back and look at it some time after you done some linear algebra.

Comment: Sorry mathreadler, can you give me a hint?

Comment: How do you plan to deal with the involved absolute values?

Comment: You are right @JackD'Aurizio and I can't find a way to patch it. Maybe in combination with Fourier series estimation of $|\sin(x)|$ could do it but that would be even more horribly overkill and not make for a very clean answer.